# How to combine 2 result sets

Tags: sql, join, merge, union

To solve the below question, I want to combine 2 result sets (Query #1 + Query #2) using SQL.
I've tried UNION but it didn't work. Help!

---

Question:

[image: Table grades]

---

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(student_id),
    MAX(registration_date),
    MAX(lab1)
FROM grades;
```

Query #1 result:

[image: Query1 result]

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(SUM(NVL(lab1, 0) + NVL(lab2, 0)))
FROM grades
GROUP BY student_id;
```

Query #2 result:

[image: Query2 result]

Comment: why are you grouping by student_id on your second query? you are not using student_id in the query selector

Comment: Explain "combine". Explain what that code is.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few descent attempts.  If you could edit your existing post and supply some sample data would help better show us what the underlying basis would be.  Are there multiple rows per lab1 and/or lab2.  Are there multiple classes represented?  You want a sum, but doing a max?

You need a group by per student so each student shows of their own.  So you had that.  You also had max(), but also sum().  So hopefully this will be close to what you need.

```
SELECT 
      g.student_id,
      max( g.registration_date ) NewestRegistrationDate,
      max( coalesce( g.lab1, 0 )) HighestLab1,
      max( coalesce( g.lab2, 0 )) HighestLab2,
      max( coalesce( g.lab1, 0 )) 
        + max( coalesce( g.lab2, 0 )) HighestBothLabs
   FROM 
      grades g
   group by
      g.student_id
```

At least the above will give you the per-student basis as your grid image would represent, not the final answer which apparently wants the total student and the highest grade overall.  That one, you WOULD want the count(), and ignore the group by as you want the answer over the entire set.  But do you want the highest in each lab category?  Or the highest per student with whatever the highest student's total labs are.

EX:

```
Student   Lab1   Lab2   Total
1         75     92     167
2         74     100    174
```

Here, you have two students.  The first has the highest lab1, but the second has highest total.  You need to make that determination or at least get clarification from the teacher.  If you want the highest by lab 1, you probably need something like wrapping the first query into the second.  But that too may be over what you are learning.  Using one result as basis for the outer such as.

```
select
      count(*) TotalStudents,
      Max( PerStudent.NewestRegistrationDate ) MostRecentRegistrationDate,
      Max( PerStudent.HighestLab1 ) HighestFirstLab,
      Max( PerStudent.HighestBothLabs ) HighestAllLabs
   from
      (     SELECT 
                  g.student_id,
                  max( g.registration_date ) NewestRegistrationDate,
                  max( coalesce( g.lab1, 0 )) HighestLab1,
                  max( coalesce( g.lab2, 0 )) HighestLab2,
                  max( coalesce( g.lab1, 0 )) 
                    + max( coalesce( g.lab2, 0 )) HighestBothLabs
               FROM 
                  grades g
               group by
                  g.student_id ) PerStudent
```

The inner pre-query (alias PerStudent) keeps the data at the per-student level giving you the basis to get the highest per at the OUTER query level that does NOT have the group by.  But at least running the first query to confirm the baseline of the data first.  If you dont have that correct, the outer won't make sense either.

Comment: Thank you but what I only need to use "GROUP BY" for the query #2. Since I'm supposed to display 1)the number of students, 2)the most recent data registration date, 3) the highest degree in lab1 among all students, 4) the highest degree in total(lab1+lab2) among all students.

Comment: @zzanzzani, revised answer.  And for future, don't paste images.  Better to just type the data and use spaces for alignment, much like my samples for two students.

Comment: hey thank you for being my very first teacher on Stackoverflow! I solved it!!

Comment: @zzanzzani, if this helped get you to your solution, be sure to upcheck / checkmark the answer so others know it is solved and this was what helped get you there.  So future, others with similar questions know what worked -- or at least significantly got you there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DRapp, I solved it with the code below.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) TotalStudents,
    MAX(PerStudent.MostRecentRegistrationDate) MostRecentRegistrationDate,
    MAX(PerStudent.HighestFirstLab) HighestFirstLab,
    MAX(PerStudent.SumBothLabs) HighestBothLabs
FROM
    (SELECT
        MAX(g.registration_date) MostRecentRegistrationDate,
        MAX(coalesce(g.lab1, 0)) HighestFirstLab,
        SUM(coalesce(g.lab1, 0) + coalesce(g.lab2, 0)) SumBothLabs
    FROM grades g
    GROUP BY g.student_id) PerStudent;
```